# Which Spring Java Class is behind the Spring EL hasRole method?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-el

Which Spring Java Class is behind the Spring EL `hasRole` method? I ask this, as `hasRole` behaves strange in my actual project and I want to debug to find out the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a breakpoint at the [SecurityExpressionRoot#hasRole()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/a82cab7afdb1fc58830b1c415f1874d36b2c6c92/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionRoot.java#L74-L76) method you should be good to go from there.